# Alternative that doesn't violate the Liskov substitution principle

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, liskov-substitution-principle, abc

Considering the following structure of classes:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class ModelSettings(ABC):
    ...

class BlueModelSettings(ModelSettings):
    ...

class RedModelSettings(ModelSettings):
    ...


class Model(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def compute(self, settings: ModelSettings):
        ...

class BlueModel(Model):
    def compute(self, settings: BlueModelSettings):
        ...

class RedModel(Model):
    def compute(self, settings: RedModelSettings):
        ...
```

MyPy is complaining that the implementations of `compute` in `BlueModel` and `RedModel` violate the Liskov substitution principle. I understand this and also understand why it makes sense.

My question is, instead of the above structure, what would be another approach that would satisfy the following requirements:

- base model has a contract that `compute` should receive settings, not apples or oranges
- but each specific model should accept only settings relevant to its own model kind

In a way, I essentially want that a subclass' method argument is **stricter** than what its base class stipulates, which goes directly against the Liskov principle. Which is what's telling me there might be a more suitable approach.

Note:

- `Model` is library code so it can't know of e.g. `BlueModelSettings` which is client code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `Model` to be generic in the type of `settings`.

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=ModelSettings)

class Model(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def compute(self, settings: T):
        ...

class BlueModel(Model[BlueModelSettings]):
    def compute(self, settings: BlueModelSettings):
        ...

class RedModel(Model[RedModelSettings]):
    def compute(self, settings: RedModelSettings):
        ...
```

Comment: Impressive. So to be completely square with the condition on `Settings`, we would then declare `T = TypeVar('T', bound=Settings)`, right?

Comment: Yeah. (I submitted the answer prematurely). Setting the bound ensures you can't create a subclass or instantiate `Model` with something that isn't a correct subclass of `ModelSettings`).

Comment: It doesn't remove anything to this answer, but it seems that MyPy allows instantiating `BlueModel(Model)` with no type parameter on `Model` and in this case doesn't check whether `BlueModelSettings` is a subclass of `ModelSettings` — are you aware of a MyPy setting that checks for the type parameter presence (currently it complains if it's wrong, but doesn't complain if absent)

Comment: *mypy allows `implementing`, not instantiating (typo)